# Null date type returns 1970 date value in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript, angular2-forms

Getting the data from service and subscribed the data set with interface type in angular2 (typescript).

Interface has date (startDate field name : Date type) field 
From the service if the startDate field values comes null in html page format getting the 01/01/1970 value.

```
interface :
    export class name { 
     public realStartDate?: Date
}


subscribe : 
this.data = data.map(item => new name (new Date(item.startDate))
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: item.startDate is possibly null. Put a debugger and check. `new Date(null)` return 01/01/1970

Comment: If you want to default to current date use `item.startDate ? new Date(items.startDate) : new Date()`. Also, your class is a bad idea. _never_ use `classe`s to represent server responses, prefer `interface`s for that. In this case, you don't need a wrapper object though.

Comment: @AluanHaddad—or `new Date(item.startDate || Date.now())`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG yeah that is terser, but slightly more complex since it involves calling `Date.now` to produce a `string` that gets parsed into a `Date` by `new`ing `Date`. That said, your approach is perfectly solid and correct.

Answer (score 2):

Need to add a null check for **item.startDate**.

"new Date(item.startDate)" returns 01/01/1970 when value of item.startDate is null.

Try to write it as follows:

```
subscribe : 
this.data = data.map(item => new name (item.startDate==null?new Date():new Date(item.startDate))
```

Comment: is it possible to make date empty  ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to default to current date use `item.startDate ? new Date(items.startDate) : new Date()`. Also, your class is a bad idea. Do not use classes to represent such objects, use interfaces instead.

Regardless, what you need is essentially

**dated.ts**

```
export interface Dated { 
  realStartDate?: Date;
}
```

**service-items-service.ts**

```
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Dated} from './dated';

@Inject export default class DatedItemsService {
  constructor(readonly http: Http) {}      

  get(id): Observable<Dated> {
    return this.http.get(`/api/v1/dateditems/${id}`)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(({startDate}) => ({
        realStartDate: startDate ? new Date(startDate): undefined
      });
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on comments, it appears an empty value is desired in place of the current date, so I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: My requirement to get the empty value not the current date value. 
Thx

Comment: I see, would be nice if you had said that before :) one sec.

Comment: I have made the below code changes, it's working fine getting the null value in template.

Interface :  public startDate : Date = null;
Subscribe :  item.startDate ? new Date(item.startDate ) : null;

Thx a lot.

Comment: Glad that works, but avoid using `null` to represent missing values, it has many pitfalls in JavaScript including the one which caused the original bug.